# Put Page Name before URL

Tags: html, domain-name

I'm making a web application and i'm just wondering about the domain name. I want it like google does it where its like maps.google instead of google . com / maps

How do i do this when buying a domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called `subdomains`.

Any URL you buy can have any subdomain by adding a DNS record.

So if you buy example.com, you already have anything.example.com.

I suggest you read up on DNS a bit. [This should get you started](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-dns-665).

Comment: Awesome! Thats what i needed to know, they are called subdomains. Ill read up on it now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating subdomians via using your control panel

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different levels of domain when it comes to DNS.

The first level is [the top domain level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). You cannot buy the top domain as they are the base of all domains and include the infamous `.com` or `.org`.

The **second level** is the one you can buy. You buy a domain related to a first level domain. So if you wanted `akashkodesia.com` you need to make sure it is available on the `.com` top domain and try to buy it.

Once you bought a domain, **the subsequent levels** are **up to you**. You can create whatever you want without asking anyone. Of course you have the restriction of the DNS protocol which is [up to 255 characters total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290167/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-dns-name) for your complete DNS name including dots.