# kubernetes label name 63 character limit

Tags: kubernetes

As explained at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/ 
labels name and value have limit of 63 characters. Does anyone know what drives this limit? I am not looking for code condition but the real reason behind choosing this value.

Comment: Hi, They are just following the requirement of [RFC-1123](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123). In Simple words, it means that they can’t be more than 63 characters in length or include anything other than lower case letters, numbers, and hyphens.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi then I would like to know why this number was chosen in RFC-1123

Comment: Hi, You could read this paper which was linked to my previous comment.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi, I just had a quick glance at it but couldn't find any reason mentioned. right now, reading entire paper is not possible for me. I would try to piggy back on community knowledge.

Comment: hi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290167/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-dns-name#32294443 Here you can see explanation.

Comment: And Here you can see the commit which changed kubernetes to have 63 characters https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/1830

Comment: Does anyone know a way to increase this limit ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [Suresh Vishnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8803619/suresh-vishnoi) wrote, it is a global restriction based on [RFC-1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290167/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-dns-name#32294443) is a simple explanation of this restriction.

[There is](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/1830)  a commit in Kubernetes which provides the validation of labels' length.

Comment: This still doesn't explain the reason. *Why* do labels need to comply with RFC-1123?

Comment: Because Kubernets pod, service, and namespace names are used by kube-dns to create DNS records. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: @KarlKFI no questions to pod, service and namespace names: why have **labels** be so short? As per https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1297 there was no _technical_ reason for that, kubernetes dev team just decided to have it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is design documentation of the kubernetes. The following link provides detail information.

> rfc1035/rfc1123 label (DNS_LABEL): An alphanumeric (a-z, and 0-9) string, with a maximum length of 63 characters, with the '-' character allowed anywhere except the first or last character, suitable for use as a hostname or segment in a domain name.

[identifiers-and-names-in-kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/architecture/identifiers.md#identifiers-and-names-in-kubernetes)

Comment: That means, we cannot have '.' in the hostnames? But I am sure this is allowed: ip-192-168-144-98.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal

Comment: I think Dot is special character in the domain name, its allowed to use, check it out here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035